# Submitting score to android leaderboards

Tags: java, android, google-play

I finally got my leaderboards and sign in working on my app but when I play my game and reopen the leaderboards there are no scores in the leaderboards still. I am having trouble submitting the highscore.

I use the code to submit:   `Games.Leaderboards.submitScoreImmediate(getApiClient(), String.valueOf(R.string.number_guesses_leaderboard),oldScore)`;

My OnCreate:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_over);

  mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
                        // add other APIs and scopes here as needed
                .build();

 int newScore = GameOver.score;


        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        int oldScore = prefs.getInt("key", 0);
        if (newScore > oldScore) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
            edit.putInt("key", newScore);
            edit.commit();
  } else {


            EditText HighScore = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.HighScoreT);
            HighScore.setText("" + oldScore);
  Games.Leaderboards.submitScoreImmediate(getApiClient(), String.valueOf(R.string.number_guesses_leaderboard),oldScore);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

R.string.number_guesses_leaderboard ends up being a unique integer defined by the android tooling that uniquely identifies your number_guesses_leaderboard string.  This is known as a resource identifier.  For example, this might be set to something like 0x7f0603fb; in your R.java file.

When you do String.valueOf(R.string.number_guesses_leaderboard), you are literally turning the integer value 0x7f0603fb into a String representation of that number.

So, unless "2131100667" is the id of your leaderboard, I don't think this is what you intended.

Instead, try doing this (assuming, of course, the value for this string resource is indeed the id of your leaderboard):

```
Games.Leaderboards.submitScoreImmediate(getApiClient(), 
    getString(R.string.number_guesses_leaderboard),oldScore);
```

You might also consider setting translatable="false" on this string or moving it do ids.xml instead since this really shouldn't be translated.

Answer (score 0):

this is a better way, i used this and it work for me , help it's useful

```
Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(myclient, 
                getString(R.string.number_guesses_leaderboard),  
                HighScore);
```